# flutter getx package not working, showing error

Tags: flutter, flutter-getx

I recently upgraded flutter. After upgrading, when I going to use **Get** it's showing down error.
without adding **get** my project work fine.

> **Codes**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutterfire_auth/src/homepage.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';

void main() {
  return runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GetMaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter App',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Homepage(),
    );
  }
}
```

> errors

```
/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/get-3.15.0/lib/get_navigation/src/extension_navigation.dart:235:37: Error: No named parameter with the name 'shadowThemeOnly'.
    final theme = Theme.of(context, shadowThemeOnly: true);
                                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/theme.dart:119:20: Context: Found this candidate, but the arguments don't match.
  static ThemeData of(BuildContext context) {
                   ^^
```

Comment: Add this to your package's pubspec.yaml file: `dependencies: get: ^3.15.0` . You can install packages from the command line: `flutter pub get`. Now in your Dart code, you can use: `import 'package:get/get.dart';`. Is this work for you?

Answer (score 0):

add pub dependency extension in vscode  "Pubspec Dependency Search" ,it will help in automitacally add "get" dependency

Answer (score 0):

Run this command: `flutter pub add get`